# Create a list of functions using R?

Tags: r

I have the following R Code (the last part of this question), after the last line I expect to get a list of 4 "retFun" functions, each initialized with a different x so that I get the following result

```
funList[[1]](1) == 7 #TRUE
funList[[2]](1) == 8 #TRUE
```

And so on, but what I seem to get is

```
funList[[1]](1) == 10 #TRUE
funList[[2]](1) == 10 #TRUE
```

As if each function in the list has the same x value

```
creatFun <- function(x, y)
{
  retFun <-  function(z)
  {
    z + x + y

  }
}


myL <- c(1,2,3,4)
funList <-sapply(myL, creatFun, y = 5)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be (and probably is, somewhere) an exercise on how lazy evaluation works in R. You need to force the evaluation of `x` before the creation of each function:

```
creatFun <- function(x, y)
{
    force(x)
  retFun <-  function(z)
  {
    z + x + y
  }
}
```

...and to be safe, you should probably `force(y)` as well for the times when you aren't passing a single value in for that parameter.

A good discussion can be found in Hadley's forthcoming book, particularly the section on [lazy evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html) in the Functions chapter (scroll down).